# Why does my hash always come out as all 0s?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, mysqli, md5

Here's my function:

```
function process_image($path) {
    global $mysqli;
    list($width,$height) = getimagesize($path);
    $hash = md5_file($path,true);
    $pic = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO pictures () VALUES ()');
    $pic->execute();
    $pic_id = $pic->insert_id;
    $size = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO picture_sizes (filename, type, picture_id, hash, width, height) VALUES (?,'FULL',?,?,?,?)");
    $size->bind_param('sibii',$path,$pic_id,$hash,$width,$height);
    if(!$size->execute()) {
        echo $size->error.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

The 'hash' field always shows up as 0s in my database. I've got it set to `BINARY(16)`. I'm guessing I'm using `$size->bind_param` incorrectly, but I can't figure out how to do it properly. `$hash` is binary, so I should be using `b` with it, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>In case of an error, md5_file returns `false`, which is converted to `0` when stored in the database. Check if the function returns false using the `===` operator.</strike>

Because the hash is a string, you can make the parameter of the type `s` (string).

Comment: It's not returning false. I tried outputting it. Looks fine. Pretty sure it has to do with my insert.

Comment: What happens if you try to use `s` instead of `b` for the parameter type?

Comment: yea I'm confused as to why a hash is being typed as a blob

Comment: Because of the field type in the database. But if it makes sense that doesn't mean it's right. Although it could be. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol: Hrm....that appears to be working now. I was using `b` because it's binary data. I didn't think you could use `s` for that.

Comment: The field is binary, but the value you send is a string. The type indicators for bind_param specifies the type of the parameter and the way it is sent. It doesn't necessarily match the field type. It couldn't, because only few (4 I think) types of parameters are supported.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Yes, but I didn't realize my variable was a string :) Thought it was a special binary type, but I just called `gettype` on it, and it is indeed a string. This makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

You may have to look at the bind param and see if you have to put in a place holder to account for 'FULL'. The insert statement is set to put `type` before picture_id, but in your bind_param you have no reference to `type`. So it may be that MySQL is trying to populate `hash` with `picture_id`.

Comment: The type, 'FULL', is a string constant and not a parameter at all. bind_param just matches parameters indicated using question marks. It is not really expecting values for each field in the field list of the insert.

Comment: 'FULL' gets inserted into the right field in the DB. I didn't put a placeholder for it because bind_param expects all references, and 'FULL' is a constant/not a reference, so I couldn't do it without binding it to a variable first.

Comment: Mark: Ahhh ok, been a long time since I used mysqli so I wasn't sure, looked like it might be an offset issue.